# How to convert points to radians in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, radians

In my app I'm using UIBezierPath to draw an arc into a circle. I'm trying to correlate a number to radians. So let's say a user has a certain number of points, and the points are capped at 100 points. I want 100 points to be 360 degrees. I want the first 33% of the circle to be green, and then from 34% to the next 66% of the circle to be stroked in orange, and then from 67% to 100% in red.

The issue I'm having here is converting percents of a circle to radians. When creating a UIBezier path, I need to provide a startAngle and endAngle, and I'm having a bit of trouble converting these points to radian values.

How would I go about solving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
CGFloat radians = percent * 0.01 * 2 * M_PI;
```

Simple algebra.

### Swift version

Making it more general purpose, you can write a conversion function:

```
func radiansFromPercent(_ percent: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return percent * 0.01 * 2 * CGFloat.pi
}
```

Comment: My apologies, but why are you multiplying by 0.01?

Comment: Your input percent ranges from 0 to 100. You want a decimal value from .01 to 1.0

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the unit circle. Remember back to trigonometry when you used the unit circle? Same thing will apply here. If you need to get π - in Swift just say `let π = CGFloat.pi` (hold alt+p for the special character). In Objective-C - I think it's `CGFloat π = M_PI;`.

[image]

You could go from zero to `2π/3` for the first 1/3, then from `2π/3` to `4π/3`, then from `4π/3` to `2π` (full circle).

I should not that I didn't make this graphic - it's from a tutorial on RayWenderlich.com - but it's oriented perfectly for the iOS coordinate system.

Comment: You can't use special characters for variable names in Objective-C like a can in Swift. You'd need to use "pi",  and you're correct the constant is M_PI

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C

```
CGFloat fullCircle = 2 * M_PI ;             // M_PI Pi number which is half of the circle in radian
CGFloat startPoint = 0.0      ;
CGFloat endPoint   = fullCircle * 0.33 ;

// Assuming circling clockwise

// .... Draw first step UIBezierPath

startPoint = endPoint        ;
endPoint = startPoint + fullCircle * 0.33 ;
// .... Draw second step UIBezierPath

startPoint = endPoint        ;
endPoint = fullCircle - startPoint ;       // This to make sure the whole circle will be covered
// .... Draw the last step UIBezierPath
```

Swift

```
let fullCircle = 2 * M_PI             // M_PI Pi number which is half of the circle in radian
var startPoint: Float = 0.0
var endPoint: Float = fullCircle * 0.33

// Assuming circling clockwise
// .... Draw first step UIBezierPath

startPoint = endPoint
endPoint = startPoint + fullCircle * 0.33
// .... Draw second step UIBezierPath

startPoint = endPoint
endPoint = fullCircle - startPoint       // This to make sure the whole circle will be covered
// .... Draw the last step UIBezierPath
```

Comment: The OP's question specified Objective-C, not Swift.